# If else redundant code to a simpler form

Tags: java, if-statement

How to represent the following `if else` condition in a better way?

```
        if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(A) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
            System.out.println("Case 1");
        } else if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(A) && StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
            System.out.println("Case 2");
        } else if ((StringUtils.isEmpty(A) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
            System.out.println("Case 3");
        } else if ((StringUtils.isEmpty(A) && StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
            System.out.println("Case 4");
        } else {
            System.out.println("End");
        }
```

Comment: Case 1 and Case 4 have the same condition.

Comment: For a start why not booleans for `aEmpty = StringUtils.isEmpty(A)` and `bEmpty = StringUtils.isEmpty(B)` to reduce the clutter.

Comment: Start with using `isNotEmpty(String str)` as well for better code readability.

Comment: you won't need fifth end condition if all 4 combinations are handled

Comment: @DevendraLattu just edited it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `Case 1` and `Case 4` are not supposed to have the same condition, which eliminates the possibility of `End`, you can do this:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(A)) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
        System.out.println("Case 4");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Case 3");
    }
} else {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(B)) {
        System.out.println("Case 2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Case 1");
    }
}
```

Or you can use a switch statement, with a little bit-math:

```
switch ((StringUtils.isEmpty(A) ? 2 : 0) | (StringUtils.isEmpty(B) ? 1 : 0)) {
    case 0: // !empty(A) & !empty(B)
        System.out.println("Case 1");
        break;
    case 1: // !empty(A) & empty(B)
        System.out.println("Case 2");
        break;
    case 2: // empty(A) & !empty(B)
        System.out.println("Case 3");
        break;
    default: // empty(A) & empty(B)
        System.out.println("Case 4");
}
```

Comment: What a shame that your second solution wasn't simply `System.out.println("Case " + (((StringUtils.isEmpty(A) ? 2 : 0) | (StringUtils.isEmpty(B) ? 1 : 0)) + 1));`

Comment: I personally didn't like the second solution and won't suggest to anyone. It is smart but difficult to understand.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I'm assuming that question is sample [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code and OP doesn't actually want to print the word `Case` and a number. We encourage MCVE questions on this site, so we shouldn't punish a question that actually does it.

Comment: @Andreas My tongue is lodged firmly in my cheek.

Comment: @sidgate Well, to be honest, I personally don't like second solution of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679693/5221149) either, because it assumes that question is literal on what is desired, and not an MCVE showcasing the question about the redundant `if` conditions, with placeholder `print` code for unimportant action taken for each case. Sure, question could have been literal, but I doubt it.

Comment: I agree. In real life, we always do some action based on some condition. Now that action can just return void, in which case my second solution won't work. But I just wanted to show alternatives that makes code better.

Answer (score 3):

This is the clearest way I can think of, to write your example.

Note that I've used the standard Java convention of lower case letters for identifiers.  If you really have named your variables `A` and `B`, for whatever reason, you might consider using more standard names.

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty;

...

if (isEmpty(a)) {
    if (isEmpty(b)) {
        System.out.println("Case 4");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Case 3");
    }
} else {
    if (isEmpty(b)) {
        System.out.println("Case 2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Case 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: And I even retain case of `A` and `B` ;-)

Comment: @Andreas you do - but OP asked for "a better way", which is why I changed the case.

Comment: But that won't then compile, unless the code declaring and assigning `A` and `B` are changed too, and you don't say anything about why you changed case and what needs to go with it. You don't even mention getting rid of `println("End")`.

Comment: @Andreas I have edited my solution as a result of your feedback.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have smaller functions for each condition for better readability.

Also, you don't need fifth condition, and reordering the conditions make it more readable

```
    import static <pkg>.StringUtils.isEmpty;

    if (bothEmpty(A,B)) {
        System.out.println("Case 4");
    } else if (isEmpty(A)) {
       System.out.println("Case 2");
    } else if (isEmpty(B)) {
        System.out.println("Case 3");
    } else  {
       System.out.println("Case 1");
    }

  boolean bothEmpty(String A, String B){
     return isEmpty(A) && isEmpty(B);
  }
```

I usually return the value if a condition satisfies. This avoids some duplication and nested if-else cases.

```
 public originalAction(String A, String B){
     System.out.println(value(A,B));
 }
 String value(String A, String B){
    if (bothEmpty(A,B))  return "Case 4";
    if (isEmpty(A)) return "Case 2";
    if (isEmpty(B)) return "Case 3";
    return "Case 1";
}
boolean bothEmpty(String A, String B){
   return isEmpty(A) && isEmpty(B);
}
```

Comment: Since you're talking about readability - it's often useful to be able to run one's eye down the left hand side of each line of code, to find exit points from the method (`return` or `throw`).  If you put the word `return` in the middle of a line, like you've done in your second solution, it's easy to miss, and therefore the flow of the method can be misunderstood.  My experience is that you get better readability if the words `return`, `break` or `throw` only ever occur at the beginning of a line.

Comment: multiple return statements has always been a debatable subject and more of personal preference. https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: And I think you'll find that when Fowler wrote that page, he had considerably less programming experience than I currently do.  Both examples on that page are less readable than they could be.

Comment: if-else statements has always been a nightmare for me as well. I choose different ways everyday, mostly based on the scenario. As @andreas pointed out, my second solution will not work if we have to perform some action with no result. But I always prefer it if there is some return value and for me it is more readable.

Comment: I'm not querying the fact that you're using `return` - I think that's a good idea, if the example really is as simple as OP suggests.  My issue is that you've written `return` in the middle of the line.  It would have been better if you had used `{` and `}` for each `if` statement, and put `return "Case X";` on its own line; so that I encounter the `return` statement as I pass my eye over the jagged left edge of the code.

Comment: Oh,you mean needBraces
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#NeedBraces